# pids.current lower than pids.max but threads cannot be created in Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, vps

**Problem**
I have a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 4vCore and 8GB of RAM. I don't know exactly the max nprocs for this VPS.

**What have I done/tried**
I run this command `sudo cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.current` to see current processes and the output is 73. Then I run this command `sudo cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.max` and the output is 400. I assume my VPS has more than 300 threads to create. I have run this C program to test hoy many threads I can create:

```
/* compile with:   gcc -pthread -o thread-limit thread-limit.c */
/* originally from: http://www.volano.com/linuxnotes.html */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 100000
#define PTHREAD_STACK_MIN 1*1024*1024*1024
int i;

void run(void) {
  sleep(60 * 60);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rc = 0;
  pthread_t thread[MAX_THREADS];
  pthread_attr_t thread_attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);

  printf("Creating threads ...\n");
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS && rc == 0; i++) {
    rc = pthread_create(&(thread[i]), &thread_attr, (void *) &run, NULL);
    if (rc == 0) {
      pthread_detach(thread[i]);
      if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0)
    printf("%i threads so far ...\n", i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Failed with return code %i creating thread %i (%s).\n",
         rc, i + 1, strerror(rc));

      // can we allocate memory?
      char *block = NULL;
      block = malloc(65545);
      if(block == NULL)
        printf("Malloc failed too :( \n");
      else
        printf("Malloc worked, hmmm\n");
    }
  }
sleep(60*60); // ctrl+c to exit; makes it easier to see mem use
  exit(0);
}
```

Source: [thread-limit.c](https://askubuntu.com/a/883677)

And this is the output:

```
sebo@h2885222:~$ ./thread-limit
Creating threads ...
Failed with return code 11 creating thread 10 (Resource temporarily unavailable).
Malloc worked, hmmm
```

I can only create 10 more threads, which I find curious. Is there any limit that is setting my VPS to not go beyond that amount of threads? Is the `pids.max` file false?

Answer (score 0):

Error code 11 looks like `EAGAIN`:

```c
// /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h
#define   EAGAIN          11      /* Try again */
```

From `man pthread_create`:

> ```
>    EAGAIN A system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.
>           There  are  a  number of limits that may trigger this error: the
>           RLIMIT_NPROC soft resource limit (set via  setrlimit(2)),  which
>           limits  the  number of processes and threads for a real user ID,
>           was reached; the kernel's system-wide limit  on  the  number  of
>           processes and threads, /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max, was reached
>           (see proc(5)); or the maximum  number  of  PIDs,  /proc/sys/ker‐
>           nel/pid_max, was reached (see proc(5)).
> ```

That gives you some ideas about what limitations you're running up against.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I already searched those limits and are far beyond of my actual limits. `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` gives me 2832149 and `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` gives me 999999. My question was related to the actual my of threads my VPS provider applies

Comment: @SebastianA you didn't mention anything about `RLIMIT_NPROC`, which was the new bit of information here.